# CLLocationManager does not worked in iphone 4 ios

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, iphone-4

My Mac os version is 10.6.4 and xcode version is 3.2.3.I'm using WhereAmI program.I have used CLLocationManager to get current location it works fine in iphone 3 ios but does not works in iphone 4 ios.Can anybody tell me what is the problem.I'm not understanding what is the problem.I thing this problem is related to GPS Setting but not understanding.Please help me. 
thanks in advance.......

Comment: You're going to need to provide more info; screen shots or code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Location Services" are turned on, on your iPhone 4 and *"WhereAmI"* can use location services.

```
Settings.app > General > Location Services
```

In the below image "ATM UK" and Camera **cannot** use location services.

[image: Settings.app - General - Location Services]